# Migrate Azure machine to Google Compute Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, azure, iis-8, vhd, google-compute-engine

We would like to migrate our SaaS offer from Azure to Google Cloud Engine.

Our current solution:

Run on Windows 2012 server, while the current offering by Google
   enables the usage of Windows 2008 Server R2. Our server heavily uses
   Web Sockets that are supported only from IIS 8. 
We have several options:

- Find a way to install IIS 8 on Windows 2008 Server R2.    (we didn’t
  find such way and IIS8 express edition can’t do the work)
- Migrate the Azure’s Image (vhd format... large file) and use it as
  image for the google VM instance.

My questions:

- Is there another way to tackle the above problem?
- Is there a way to run IIS 8 (with WebSockets support) on Windows 2008
  Server R2?
- What is the best way to create Google VM Instance from VHD or iso? Do
  you have a documentation for this process? (Step by Step preferred)

thanks, R.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Would you please narrow the scope of your post so that it could have a single objectively best answer? Right now it's three questions rolled in one post.

Comment: Done:                               http://serverfault.com/questions/659529/run-iis-8-on-windows-2008-server-r2

Answer (score 2):

Windows 2012 R2 is [now available on GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/operating-systems/windows).

Answer (score 1):

Note that as per http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/ you will loose your license key when exporting your AWS Windows instance, additionally you have to work through resolving the differences between the requirements of the two platforms. Also read the article 'Microsoft license mobility' on the GCE Windows documentation site. Currently you can not import VHD or ISO files to GCE, however you can import Virtual Box images (search for VHD to Virtualbox the) https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#import_a_virtualbox_image and Amazon Machine Image (AMI) however only Linux ones for now.

Therefore in summary unless you need this transition regularly to run with multiple providers I suggest to reinstall, which might be slower but a less troublesome path.