# Run IIS 8 on Windows 2008 Server R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8

Is there a way to install and run IIS8 on Windows Server 2008 R2?

We need it for the WebSocket support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The full version of IIS 8.0 is only available on Server 2012 (and Windows 8)](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012).  That's how it goes with IIS - a new major version of IIS for a new major version of Windows.  R2 OS releases get a ".5" release of IIS.

[However, IIS 8.0 *Express* is available and supported on Server 2008 R2](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-80-express-readme), so you might be able to made do with that.  If not, you'll have to upgrade your Server OS to get an IIS version that works for you.